# Running cron python jobs within docker

Tags: python, cron, docker

I would like to run a python cron job inside of a docker container in detached mode. My set-up is below:

My python script is test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime
print "Cron job has run at %s" %datetime.datetime.now()
```

My cron file is my-crontab

```
* * * * * /test.py > /dev/console
```

and my Dockerfile is

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties && apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y python cron
ADD my-crontab /
ADD test.py /
RUN chmod a+x test.py

RUN crontab /my-crontab
ENTRYPOINT cron -f
```

What are the potential problems with this approach? Are there other approaches and what are their pros and cons?

Comment: Interesting idea.  Would not have thought of this, though I often run cron in containers using supervisord.

Comment: @seanmcl I would be very interested in learning how you do that using supervisord. Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: I have a docker container that uses environment variables during execution of a CRON job python script. Here is a link to what I provided as an answer in another SO post, http://stackoverflow.com/a/41938139/5090330

Comment: Note to future self; Depending on the container, make sure cron service is actually running `service cron status` -> `service cron start`

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/gjcarneiro/yacron is interesting for you. It claims to be `A modern Cron replacement that is Docker-friendly`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Several issues that I faced while trying to get a cron job running in a docker container were:

1. time in the docker container is in UTC not local time;
2. the docker environment is not passed to cron;
3. as Thomas noted, cron logging leaves a lot to be desired and accessing it through docker requires a docker-based solution.

There are cron-specific issues and are docker-specific issues in the list, but in any case they have to be addressed to get cron working.

To that end, my current working solution to the problem posed in the question is as follows:

Create a docker volume to which all scripts running under cron will write:

```
# Dockerfile for test-logs

# BUILD-USING:        docker build -t test-logs .
# RUN-USING:          docker run  -d -v /t-logs --name t-logs test-logs
# INSPECT-USING:      docker run -t -i  --volumes-from t-logs ubuntu:latest /bin/bash

FROM stackbrew/busybox:latest

# Create logs volume
VOLUME /var/log

CMD  ["true"]
```

The script that will run under cron is `test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# python script which needs an environment variable and runs as a cron job
import datetime
import os

test_environ = os.environ["TEST_ENV"]
print "Cron job has run at %s with environment variable '%s'" %(datetime.datetime.now(), test_environ)
```

In order to pass the environment variable to the script that I want to run under cron, follow Thomas' suggestion and put a crontab fragment for each script (or group of scripts) that has need of a docker environment variable in `/etc/cron.d` with a placeholder `XXXXXXX` which must be set.

```
# placed in /etc/cron.d 
# TEST_ENV is an docker environment variable that the script test.py need

TEST_ENV=XXXXXXX
#
* * * * * root python /test.py >> /var/log/test.log
```

Instead of calling cron directly, wrap cron in a python script that does does things: 1. reads the environment variable from the docker environment variable and sets the environment variable in a crontab fragment.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# run-cron.py
# sets environment variable crontab fragments and runs cron

import os
from subprocess import call
import fileinput

# read docker environment variables and set them in the appropriate crontab fragment
environment_variable = os.environ["TEST_ENV"]

for line in fileinput.input("/etc/cron.d/cron-python",inplace=1):
    print line.replace("XXXXXXX", environment_variable)

args = ["cron","-f", "-L 15"]
call(args)
```

The `Dockerfile` that for the container in which the cron jobs run is as follows:

```
# BUILD-USING:        docker build -t test-cron .
# RUN-USING docker run --detach=true --volumes-from t-logs --name t-cron test-cron

FROM debian:wheezy
#
# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root
ENV TEST_ENV test-value

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common python-software-properties && apt-get update

# Install Python Setuptools
RUN apt-get install -y python cron

RUN apt-get purge -y python-software-properties software-properties-common && apt-get clean -y && apt-get autoclean -y && apt-get autoremove -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

ADD cron-python /etc/cron.d/
ADD test.py /
ADD run-cron.py /

RUN chmod a+x test.py run-cron.py

# Set the time zone to the local time zone
RUN echo "America/New_York" > /etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

CMD ["/run-cron.py"]
```

Finally, create the containers and run them:

1. Create the log volume (test-logs) container: `docker build -t test-logs .`
2. Run log volume: `docker run  -d -v /t-logs --name t-logs test-logs`
3. Create the cron container: `docker build -t test-cron .`
4. Run the cron container: `docker run --detach=true --volumes-from t-logs --name t-cron test-cron`
5. To inspect the log files of the scripts running under cron: `docker run -t -i  --volumes-from t-logs ubuntu:latest /bin/bash`. The log files are in `/var/log`.

Comment: Would `TEST_ENV=test-value cron -f -L 15` not work for the command?

Comment: I uploaded this code on github to make it more convenient https://github.com/Alexis-benoist/docker-cron-example

Comment: For it to work, I required this in my Dockerfile `RUN chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/cron-python` because "the files in /etc/cron.d must be owned by root, and must not be group- or other-writable." [from 'man cron'].  Before this, my `cron-python` file was group-writable.

Comment: very well explained, specially issues. but too complicated for my simple usage, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61631500) did the job

Answer (score 17):

Here is a complement on rosksw answer.

There is no need to do some string replacement in the crontab file in order to pass environment variables to the cron jobs.

It is simpler to store the environment variables in a file when running the contrainer, then load them from this file at each cron execution. I found the tip [here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/draffensperger/postgres-s3-backup/dockerfile/).

In the dockerfile:

```
CMD mkdir -p /data/log && env > /root/env.txt && crond -n
```

In the crontab file:

```
* * * * * root env - `cat /root/env.txt` my-script.sh
```

Comment: Had to use `export $(cat /root/env-params | xargs)` to load the env afterwards. Then it worked

Comment: this technique worked for me. its also explained here:
https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2016/02/29/docker-crontab-environment-variables/

Answer (score 8):

Adding crontab fragments in `/etc/cron.d/` instead of using root's `crontab` might be preferable.

This would:

- Let you add additional cron jobs by adding them to that folder.
- Save you a few layers.
- Emulate how Debian distros do it for their own packages.

Observe that the format of those files is a bit different from a crontab entry. Here's a sample from the Debian php package:

```
# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
#  as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
#  files, or 24 minutes if not defined.  See /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime)
```

Overall, from experience, running cron in a container does work very well (besides cron logging leaving a lot to be desired).

Answer (score 7):

We are using below solution. It supports both `docker logs` functionality and ability to hang the cron process in the container on PID 1 (if you use `tail -f` workarounds provided above - if cron crashes, docker will not follow restart policy):

**`cron.sh:`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printenv | cat - /etc/cron.d/cron-jobs > ~/crontab.tmp \
    && mv ~/crontab.tmp /etc/cron.d/cron-jobs

chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/cron-jobs

tail -f /var/log/cron.log &

cron -f
```

**`Dockerfile:`**

```
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q cron 

ADD cron.sh /usr/bin/cron.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/cron.sh

ADD ./crontab /etc/cron.d/cron-jobs
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron-jobs

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/usr/bin/cron.sh"]
```

**`crontab:`**

```
* * * * * root <cmd> >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

And please don't forget to add the creepy new line in your crontab

Answer (score 7):

Don't mix crond and your base image. Prefer to use a native solution for your language (schedule or crython as said by Anton), or decouple it. By decoupling it I mean, keep things separated, so you don't have to maintain an image just to be the fusion between python and crond.

You can use [Tasker](http://github.com/opsxcq/tasker), a task runner that has cron (a scheduler) support, to solve it, if you want keep things decoupled.

Here an `docker-compose.yml` file, that will run some tasks for you

```
version: "2"

services:
    tasker:
        image: strm/tasker
        volumes:
            - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
        environment:
            configuration: |
                logging:
                    level:
                        ROOT: WARN
                        org.springframework.web: WARN
                        sh.strm: DEBUG
                schedule:
                    - every: minute
                      task: helloFromPython
                tasks:
                    docker:
                        - name: helloFromPython
                          image: python:3-slim
                          script:
                              - python -c 'print("Hello world from python")'
```

Just run `docker-compose up`, and see it working. Here is the Tasker repo with the full documentation:

http://github.com/opsxcq/tasker

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative solution.

in `Dockerfile`

```
ADD docker/cron/my-cron /etc/cron.d/my-cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/my-cron

ADD docker/cron/entrypoint.sh /etc/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/etc/entrypoint.sh"]
```

in `entrypoint.sh`

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
  printenv | cat - /etc/cron.d/my-cron > ~/my-cron.tmp \
    && mv ~/my-cron.tmp /etc/cron.d/my-cron

cron -f
```

Comment: Be sure to add the `-f`!  If you don't, you get some weird behavior -- like not being able to shell into the box.  (`docker exec` may not work)

Answer (score 6):

Here is my checklist for debugging cron python scripts in docker:

1. Make sure you run `cron` command somewhere. Cron doesn't start automatically. You can run it from a Dockerfile using `RUN` or `CMD` or add it to a startup script for the container. In case you use `CMD` you may consider using `cron -f` flag which keeps cron in the foreground and won't let container die. However, I prefer using `tail -f` on logfiles.
2. Store environment variables in /etc/envoronment. Run this from a bash startscript: `printenv > /etc/environment`. This is an absolute must if you use environment variables inside of python scripts. Cron doesn't know anything about the environment variables by default. By it can read them from `/etc/environment`.
3. Test Cron by using the following config:

```
* * * * * echo "Cron works" >>/home/code/test.log
* * * * * bash -c "/usr/local/bin/python3 /home/code/test.py >>/home/code/test.log 2>/home/code/test.log"
```

The python test file should contain some `print` statements or something else that displays that the script is running. `2>/home/code/test.log` will also log errors. Otherwise, you won't see errors at all and will continue guessing.

Once done, go to the container, using `docker exec -it <container_name> bash` and check:

1. That crontab config is in place using `crontab -l`
2. Monitor logs using `tail -f /home/code/test.log`

I have spent hours and days figuring out all of those problems. I hope this helps someone to avoid this.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use [Crython](https://github.com/ahawker/crython). Crython allows you to regularly schedule a python function from within a single python script / process. It even understands cron syntax:

```
@crython.job(expr='0 0 0 * * 0 *')
def job():
    print "Hello world"
```

Using crython avoids the various headaches of running crond inside a docker container - your job is now a single process that wakes up when it needs to, which fits better into the docker execution model. But it has the downside of putting the scheduling inside your program, which isn't always desirable. Still, it might be handy in some use cases.

Comment: This library sucks.  I couldn't get it to work.  The default version in `pip` is horribly broken (fires any job every second).  And the `expr` syntax will trick you because it's not compatible with cron.

Comment: I ended up going with the python `schedule` package instead.  https://github.com/dbader/schedule

Comment: @TimLudwinski : how are making the python schedule code running inside the docker container - i am trying to do nohup python -u ./run-scheduler.py > cmd.log & - but that quits when i do logout

Comment: I would suspect your problem might be that you shouldn't be using `nohup` with docker processes.  That puts the process in the background and docker is probably quiting when the main foreground process quits.

Answer (score 3):

#### Single Container Method

You may run `crond` within the same container that is [doing something closely related](http://blog.tutum.co/2014/10/28/the-5-most-important-things-ive-learned-from-using-docker/) using a base image that handles PID 0 well, like [phusion/baseimage](https://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/).

#### Specialized Container Method

May be cleaner would be to have another Container linked to it that just runs `crond`. For example:

`Dockerfile`

```
 FROM busybox
 ADD crontab /var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data
 CMD crond -f
```

`crontab`

```
 * * * * * echo $USER
```

Then run:

```
 $ docker build -t cron .
 $ docker run --rm --link something cron
```

Note: In this case it'll run the job as `www-data`. Cannot just mount the `crontab` file as volume because it needs to be owned by `root` with only write access for `root`, else `crond` will run nothing. Also you'll have to run `crond` as `root`.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, hope it helps someone

./Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.12-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes \
 cron \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN (cat scripts/crontab) | crontab
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

ENTRYPOINT cron && python -m gunicorn main:app
```

./scripts/crontab (don't forget `LF` not `CRLF`)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin 
* * * * * /bin/bash -c 'cd /app; python -c "import datetime; print(f\" HeartBeat ⏱️ {datetime.datetime.now()}\")" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

outputs

```
PS > docker exec -it docker-app tail -f /var/log/cron.log     
 HeartBeat ⏱️ 2024-03-22 01:15:01.614985
 HeartBeat ⏱️ 2024-03-22 01:16:01.628020
...
```