# How can I access Docker set Environment Variables From a Cron Job

Tags: cron, environment-variables, docker

I've recently tried running a cron job from within a linked docker container and run into an issue. My main docker container is linked to a postgres container and its port number is set as an environment variable by docker upon the containers creation. This environment variable is not set in ~/.profile or any other source file that I could load when running my cron job. How can I then access these environment variables from my cron job?

Thanks!

Comment: This post seems to answer the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822067/running-cron-python-jobs-within-docker

Answer (score 128):

I ran into this same problem. I have a docker container that runs cron to execute some shell scripts periodically. I too had a hard time finding out why my scripts would run fine when I manually executed them inside the container. I tried all the tricks of creating a shell script that would run first to set the environment, but they never worked for me (most likely I did something wrong). But I continued looking and found this and it does work.

1. Setup a start or entry point shell script for your cron container
2. Make this the first line to execute `printenv | grep -v "no_proxy" >> /etc/environment`

The trick here is the `/etc/environment` file. When the container is built that file is empty, I think on purpose. I found a reference to this file in the man pages for [cron(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/cron.8.html). After looking at all the versions of cron they all elude to an `/etc/?` file that you can use to feed environment variables to child processes.

Also, note that I created my docker container to run cron in the foreground, `cron -f`. This helped me avoid other tricks with `tail` running to keep the container up.

Here is my entrypoint.sh file for reference and my container is a debian:jessie base image.

```
printenv | grep -v "no_proxy" >> /etc/environment

cron -f
```

Also, this trick worked even with environment variables that are set during, `docker run` commands.

Comment: printenv > /etc/environment was the only thing that worked for me after 4 days och experimenting with various options ! Thanks!

Comment: Using "/etc/environment" worked for me, however please note that reading this file is not standard behavior for cron - it only works if you have the pam cron module installed, please see https://askubuntu.com/a/700126

Comment: Watch out for the limitation of using `/etc/environment` file as there is no possibility to escape the comment sign `#`, so you can not use it in the values of the variables there...

Comment: It might be worth noting that the `... | grep -v " no_proxy` part is specific to certain environments and it's just a red herring for most.  As @Deko says, for most situations the magic is simply `printenv > /etc/environment`.  (Also, using ">>" would append to any existing /etc/environment file but I've never seen one that's not empty to start.  Does anyone have a different experience??)

Comment: Please be aware that `>>` will cause add cron line as many times as docker container restart, better just `>`

Comment: Hi @Javier, that is true if the file is mounted in. Since my file was part of the image the changes are only saved in the scratch layer that is created when all the layers are merged together in the container start. Using the `>` will just overwrite any changes you already have, so using `>` and `>>` all depends on your situation.

Comment: @TimSchruben very interesting, thanks for sharing your wisdom :)

Comment: Perfect! The simplest and workable solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. Even setting the env variables manually at the top of my crontab entries didn't solve this problem for me but this is so much more elegant and it actually works!

Comment: @TomWilson what is the environment where "no_proxy" is a problem? NO_PROXY still gets through so I assume it's not just when you don't want a proxy.

Comment: @Chrus, you got me.  I've never seen no_proxy in the wild.  I'm assuming it's an environment setting that pops up in some configurations.  `printenv > /etc/environment` does the trick for us.

Comment: How can one run the `entrypoint.sh` file from the dockerfile?

Comment: @OliverAngelil, not sure exactly what you mean. But when you build a docker image there is a stanza `ENTRYPOINT` where you specify the path to your `entrypoint.sh` file. When you docker image runs the daemon will execute that script for you. If you want to test it by getting a shell session inside your container, then run your image setting the `--entrypoint=""` and that will set it back to default. You can the run you string manually.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on debian bullseye

Answer (score 52):

I would recommend using `declare` to export your environment and avoid escaping issues. Can be used in CMD or ENTRYPOINT or directly in a wrapper script which might be called by one of them:

`declare -p | grep -Ev 'BASHOPTS|BASH_VERSINFO|EUID|PPID|SHELLOPTS|UID' > /container.env`

Grep -v takes care of filtering out read-only variables.

You can later easily load this environment like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/container.env
* * * * * root /test-cron.sh
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works much better than the first answer with printenv that doesn't escape anything

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. Using the "/etc/environment" file as others have mentioned in this thread isn't as good idea as it first seems unfortunately (ref  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97736/escape-hash-mark-in-etc-environment) :/

Comment: I think this is the right answer too, but I haven't used the "-v" of the "grep", I've preferred put the specific variables that I will use, like this:
`declare -p | grep -E 'VAR1|VAR2|VAR3|ETC' > /container.env`

Comment: Alex Fedulov's regex is too greedy. It will filter out more than the intended variable declarations (it would f.ex. filter out a variable named `FLUID`). I suggest using the expression  `declare -p | grep -Ev '^declare -[[:alpha:]]*r'` which should filter out all the readonly declarations.

Comment: @TomášPospíšek or maybe amend the pattern to respect word boundaries?:
`grep -Ev '\b(BASHOPTS|BASH_VERSINFO|EUID|PPID|SHELLOPTS|UID)\b'`, or even `'\b(BASHOPTS|BASH_VERSINFO|EUID|PPID|SHELLOPTS|UID)='`

Comment: Most elegant and bulletproof solution I found  Of course, apart of fixing this in the container runtime. BTW - anybody knows how the envs are passed between container runtime and linux OS? The env is not part of e.g. `/etc/profile` and I'm scratching my head how it is working.

Answer (score 6):

One can append the system environment variables to the top of a crontab file by using wrapper shell script to run the cron daemon. The following example is from CentOs 7,

In the Dockerfile

```
COPY my_cron /tmp/my_cron
COPY bin/run-crond.sh run-crond.sh
RUN chmod -v +x /run-crond.sh
CMD ["/run-crond.sh"]
```

run_cron.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# prepend application environment variables to crontab
env | egrep '^MY_VAR' | cat - /tmp/my_cron > /etc/cron.d/my_cron

# Run cron deamon
# -m off : sending mail is off 
# tail makes the output to cron.log viewable with the $(docker logs container_id) command
/usr/sbin/crond -m off  && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

This is based on a great blog post somewhere, but I lost the link.

Answer (score 6):

inspired by @Kannan Kumarasamy answer:

```sh
  for variable_value in $(cat /proc/1/environ | sed 's/\x00/\n/g'); do
    export $variable_value
  done
```

I can't state for sure, what process with pid1 is and that its stable during lifetime of OS. but as it is the first process to be run, inside a container i guess we can take it for granted it is a process with desired env vars set. take all of this with pich of salt unless some linux/docker docs proves this is completely ok.

Comment: Read permission only for root. And one minor note, shellcheck warns "Useless cat" and suggests using `$(sed 's/\x00/\n\g' < /proc/1/environ)` instead.

Comment: actually, you trim down further:
`sed 's/\x00/\n/g' /proc/1/environ`
sed takes a file as input and spits out the changes (unless specified otherwise, with -i inplace for example)

Answer (score 5):

You can run the following command

```sh
. <(xargs -0 bash -c 'printf "export %q\n" "$@"' -- < /proc/1/environ)
```

This is exceptionally works when you have the environment variables with special characters like `'` `"` `=`

Comment: well. have a +1 from me. but could you point us to some docs that proves pid 1 is always the process that has the original environment variables?

Comment: this one alos work with any special character in your envrionment variable.
  `eval $(printenv | awk -F= '{print "export " "\""$1"\"""=""\""$2"\"" }' >> /etc/profile)`

Answer (score 3):

You should export your environment variable before you run cronjobs.

Other solutions are fine but they will fail when there are any special characters in your environment variable.

I have found the solution:

`eval $(printenv | awk -F= '{print "export " "\""$1"\"""=""\""$2"\"" }' >> /etc/profile)`

Answer (score 2):

The environment is set, but not available to the cron job.   To fix that, you can do these two simple things

1) Save the env to a file in your ENTRYPOINT or CMD

```
CMD env > /tmp/.MyApp.env && /bin/MyApp
```

2) Then read that env into your cron command like this:

```
0 5 * * * . /tmp/.MyApp.env; /bin/MyApp
```

Comment: This won't work when env values contain characters such as whitespaces or pipes

Comment: You'll need to properly escape env vars with whitespaces or pipes.

Comment: does `.env`  file has have executable ?

Answer (score 0):

To escape any weird characters that could break your script, and according to reasoning from [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35088810/1468388), add this line to your `entrypoint.sh`:

```
env | sed -r "s/'/\\\'/gm" | sed -r "s/^([^=]+=)(.*)\$/\1'\2'/gm" \ > /etc/environment
```

This way, if you have any variable like `affinity:container==My container's friend`, it will be converted to `affinity:container='=My container\'s friend`, and so on.

Comment: Even this will fail if there's a # charater in one of the environment variables. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97736/escape-hash-mark-in-etc-environment

Answer (score 0):

Building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48651061/4290861), I made a fully functional MVP [here](https://github.com/gallet/ContainerCronMvp). I am sharing this as, being a nood, I struggled to build it and I guess I am not alone in that situation.
It also has the "benefit" of output the echoes and prints to the container log.

TLDR:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11
ENV MY_ENV_VAR="default_value"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron -y -qq

COPY cron /tmp/cron
COPY run_cron.sh run_cron.sh
RUN chmod +x run_cron.sh

COPY main.py /app/main.py

CMD ["/run_cron.sh"]
```

cron

```
*/1 * * * * root python /app/main.py > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

run_cron.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#VARIOUS IMPORTANT FILES
CRON_FILE=/tmp/cron
ENV_FILE=/container.env
CRONTAB_BAK_FILE=/etc/crontab.bak
CRONTAB_FILE=/etc/crontab

CRON_STR=$(cat $CRON_FILE)

echo "=========="
echo "Welcome to run_crond.sh, a wrapper to $CRON_STR that loads the container environment variables into the cron shell"
echo "=========="
echo ""

echo "Exporting variables to $ENV_FILE"
echo ""
declare -p | grep -Ev 'BASHOPTS|BASH_VERSINFO|EUID|PPID|SHELLOPTS|UID' > "$ENV_FILE"

if test -f "$CRONTAB_BAK_FILE"; then
  echo "Retrieving $CRONTAB_FILE from $CRONTAB_BAK_FILE"
  cp "$CRONTAB_BAK_FILE" "$CRONTAB_FILE"
else
  echo "Copying $CRONTAB_FILE to $CRONTAB_BAK_FILE"
  cp "$CRONTAB_FILE" "$CRONTAB_BAK_FILE"
fi
echo ""

echo "SHELL=/bin/bash"    >> "$CRONTAB_FILE" && \
echo "BASH_ENV=$ENV_FILE" >> "$CRONTAB_FILE" && \
echo "$CRON_STR"          >> "$CRONTAB_FILE"

echo "$CRONTAB_FILE ready:"
cat "$CRONTAB_FILE"
echo ""

## Run cron deamon
echo "starting cron deamon in the foreground"
cron -f
echo ""
```

main.py

```
import os
my_string = "Hello, World! " + os.getenv('MY_ENV_VAR')
print(my_string)
```