# Docker dump environment variables into a file

Tags: docker, environment-variables

I need my Dockerfile to create a file with the environment variables, this is in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "SENDGRID_KEY=${SENDGRID_KEY}; export SENDGRID_KEY" >> /root/.profile;
RUN echo "SENDGRID_FROM=${SENDGRID_FROM}; export SENDGRID_FROM" >> /root/.profile;
RUN echo "POSTGRES_HOST=${POSTGRES_HOST}; export POSTGRES_HOST" >> /root/.profile;
RUN echo "POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}; export POSTGRES_PORT" >> /root/.profile;
RUN echo "POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}; export POSTGRES_DB" >> /root/.profile;
RUN echo "POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}; export POSTGRES_USER" >> /root/.profile;
RUN echo "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}; export POSTGRES_PASSWORD" >> /root/.profile;
```

This is the output, instead of showing the values, it seems like the environment variables have no value

```
SENDGRID_KEY=; export SENDGRID_KEY
SENDGRID_FROM=; export SENDGRID_FROM
POSTGRES_HOST=; export POSTGRES_HOST
POSTGRES_PORT=; export POSTGRES_PORT
POSTGRES_DB=; export POSTGRES_DB
POSTGRES_USER=; export POSTGRES_USER
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=; export POSTGRES_PASSWORD
```

if I access the container with `docker exec -it django /bin/bash` and run the echo commands then the file shows the expected output, so it seems to me I'm trying to access the environment variables in a moment where they are not defined yet

Here is how I define the environment variables in the compose file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  sindgestor_local_postgres_data: {}
  sindgestor_local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: sindgestor_local_django
    container_name: sindgestor_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
      - ./.envs/.local/.sendgrid
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    command: /start
    networks:
      bridge:
        aliases:
          - sindgestor_local_django
```

Some context: I want to dump the environment variables because I need to run a cronjob that depends on these variables, and the only way I could load them was setting the cronjob like:

```
0 6 1 * * /bin/bash -c 'source /root/.profile; python /app/backend/trigger_schedule.py MORNING MONTHLY'
```

So, how can I write the values of the environment variables to `/root/.profile`?

Comment: Those `env_file` files are passed into the container. The `Dockerfile` is used to build the image, that is later used to create the container. You are trying to access environment variables at build time, that are not available until run time.

Comment: is there any way to make those variables available at build time?

Comment: Why not just move all those `echo` lines to the startup script?

Comment: If you compile those credentials into the image, you'll have to rebuild the image whenever they change, and anyone who has a copy of the image can almost trivially extract them.  [How can I access Docker set Environment Variables From a Cron Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771781/how-can-i-access-docker-set-environment-variables-from-a-cron-job) has a couple of recipes that run at container startup time, where Compose `env_file:` will be visible; does one of those approaches work for you?

Comment: @MarkB I moved the echo lines to the script in entrypoint and it worked, don't know why I didn't think of it before, thank you, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do something at *build time*, with environment variables that are only available at *run time*. The best solution would be to move those `echo` statements into your entrypoint script.