# Docker retain ENV variables

Tags: docker

I am running a docker container using `--env VAR="foo"` to set a few variables. When I run commands on this running container from the same shell / environment that I started the container, everything is fine.

The problem is that now I want to run commands against this container from cron. When cron runs the same command, the ENV variables in the container no longer exist.

How can I persist these ENV variables in the container regardless of where it is accessed from?

Edit:
To clarify, I `docker run` from a standard shell. In the cron job, I use `docker exec` and that is when the ENV vars disappear.

I have also noticed that some host machines I can't do any exec's on docker containers from a cron job.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822067/running-cron-python-jobs-within-docker ? you can use the trick of Alban Mouton, among other solutions

Comment: @user2915097 not quite, I am running a docker command from the host machine cron - not trying to run cron from within a docker container itself

Answer (score 0):

I presume you use `docker run` inside your cron task.

If that's the case that's normal. You are starting a new container from the same image.

If you want to use the same container (with all your env variables set), you can use `docker exec`.

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: I updated my question - I am using it in the way you suggest from the beginning but thats how the issue exists